# Dynamically show serial numbers in vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let me explain what exactly i am looking for. I have a project where it has quiz type interview and this interview has questions. i have 3 users type and each type has their own questions. A user can have multiple role so for example. if a user choose 2 roles so i need to show them questions for both types.

So here i am using vue js.

I have made a base component called `Interview.vue` and in this component i am having 3 more child component specifically for those type of users.

Lets say i have 3 types of user - 1) chef 2) waiter 3) barman 
So if a user choose role chef and barman so i will render those 2 components which will have questions for that particular roles.

lets say ... my `Chef.vue` has 2 questions.
and `Barman.vue` has 3 questions.

So i render these 2 components i will see 5 questions on the web page.

My question is how can i give every question a serial number. ?

Comment: how are your questions made? as in unindexed array, indexed aray, object, or something else? You got any code code for us?

Comment: questions are static i mean they are hardcoded.

Comment: Give each question a [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

Comment: @TrueCode if made the question like on object or indexed array then you can add properties to it with some unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a counter that is available globally and increments with every use.

Here's an example implementation:

```js
Vue.prototype.$elNum = 0;
Vue.prototype.$getElNum = () => Vue.prototype.$elNum += 1;
```

then whenever you are creating an element anywhere in the app, you can set the `key` or `serialNumber` by setting it to `this.$getElNum()`